# set the background color with ID

Tags: html, css, svg, background-color

I have multiple charts in my webpage,i want to change the background color of one particular chart to white and for that i have used the below css styles.

```
svg g:first-of-type rect {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}
svg g:first-of-type path {
  stroke: #e6e6e6;
}
svg g:first-of-type rect:not(:last-child) {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

With the above code it is making all the charts color in my application to white, how can i apply it to a particular chart.I tried to use the div id value in front of the svg element while declaring the styles but was not working..

Answer (score 1):

Use the id to the parent div.
Hope this helps.

```html
<style>
/*   want to make the grey color shown in chart2 to white*/
  /*  svg g:first-of-type rect {
        fill-opacity: 0;
    }
    svg g:first-of-type path {
        stroke: #e6e6e6;
    }
    svg g:first-of-type rect:not(:last-child) {
        fill: #ffffff;
    }*/
    #chartTwo{
      background-color:Red;
    }
    
</style> 

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="chartOne" google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
   <div ng-controller="myController2"  id="chartTwo">
    <div  google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your plucker said you are using different `ids` for both the charts then why don't you use that specific chart `id` to apply css like

And `backgroundColor` to `none` or `transparent` will not work in the `svg` because the color is coming from the svg `fill` property.

```
#chartTwo svg g:first-of-type rect {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}

#chartTwo svg g:first-of-type path {
  stroke: #e6e6e6;
}

#chartTwo svg g:first-of-type rect:not(:last-child) {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

**[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9cpYBohtGdwMo4mf2WMB?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

**Try This in CSS**

```
background-color: none !important;

background-color: transparent !important;
```

Use `!important` it will work..

Answer (score -2):

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="chartOne" google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>

  <br>
   <div ng-controller="myController2" class="scnd">
    <div id="chartTwo" google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

in CSS

```
.scnd
{
    /*Your style here*/
}
```

and the  styles your written was not correct

```
background-Color: 'none'
background-Color: 'transparent'
```

Comment: Neither your styles are correct. Unless it is not CSS, it should be `background-color`, all lower-case.

Comment: yeah..I agree with you , but css is not case sensitive it will accept both upper and lower cases